# What does "type name[size]" mean in a function argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I was analyzing the SKIA source code and found this:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence = 4;
// ...
SK_SPI size_t ToUTF8(SkUnichar uni, char utf8[kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence] = nullptr);
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I know (pardon me if I'm wrong) that `char utf8[kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence]` decays to `char*`, as also would `char utf8[]` or just `char* utf8`.

Therefore, I think it wouldn't make sense to write it that way, right?

Comment: Yes, writing code like that has no meaning or purpose. Especially when default value `nullptr` is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

Thus these function declarations

```
SK_SPI size_t ToUTF8(SkUnichar uni, char utf8[kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence] = nullptr);
SK_SPI size_t ToUTF8(SkUnichar uni, char utf8[10] = nullptr);
SK_SPI size_t ToUTF8(SkUnichar uni, char *utf8 = nullptr);
```

declare the same one function.

This parameter declaration

```
char utf8[kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence]
```

is used for self-docimentation specifying that the passed array must have no greater than `kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence` elements or the user can pass a null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

In a function parameter, array notation is just syntax sugar.  The size specified inside the brackets is ignored, and the actual parameter type is just a pointer.

In other words, this declaration:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence = 4;
// ...
SK_SPI size_t ToUTF8(SkUnichar uni, char utf8[kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence] = nullptr);
```

Is treated by the compiler as this:

```cpp
constexpr unsigned kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence = 4;
// ...
SK_SPI size_t ToUTF8(SkUnichar uni, char* utf8 = nullptr);
```

However, specifying the parameter declaration in array notation acts as *documentation* to programmers that the function *expects* a `char[]` array of size *at least* `kMaxBytesInUTF8Sequence` to be passed in.  But there is nothing the compiler does to actually *validate* that.